# Cross Compile Kernel Module for 4.1.2 can't find plat/dmtimer.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I am using a Beaglebone Black to try and learn how to write kernel modules. I wanted to start with something somewhat simple, so thought writing a module to control a hardware timer and blink an LED would be a relatively simple thing to accomplish.  I have downloaded the 4.1.2-bone12 source, cross compiled it, and created an SD card to boot from by following a guide written by Robert C Nelson.

I have written a .c file and Makefile for the module.  The Makefile is as follows:

```
ARCH=arm
COMPILER_LOC=/home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-4.1.2-bone12/dl/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
COMPILER=$(COMPILER_LOC)/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
KDIR := /home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-4.1.2-bone12/KERNEL

obj-m := timer.o

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(COMPILER) modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD ARCH=$(ARCH) clean
```

When I run make it throws the error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-4.1.2-bone12/KERNEL'
CC [M]  /home/tom/ti/Kernel/Timer/timer.o
/home/tom/ti/Kernel/Timer/timer.c:5:26: fatal error: plat/dmtimer.h: No such file or directory
 #include <plat/dmtimer.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/tom/ti/Kernel/Timer/timer.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/tom/ti/Kernel/Timer] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-4.1.2-bone12/KERNEL'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Originally I was using the 3.8.13-bone72 kernel and was not having this issue.  I only made 2 changes in the Makefile, the .c did not change when going from the 3.8.13-bone72 kernel to 4.1.2-bone12.  The two changes are:

```
COMPILER_LOC=/home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-3.8.13-bone72/dl/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux/bin
KDIR := /home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-3.8.13-bone72/KERNEL
```

Both the 3.8.13-bone72 and 4.1.2-bone12 sources have the dmtimer.h located in
../KERNEL/arch/arm/plat-omap/include/plat/.

So my question, why would cross compiling with the 4.1.2-bone12 kernel fail when it succeeded with the 3.8.13-bone72?

Also, for people wondering the reason I switched from the 3.8.13-bone72 to 4.1.2-bone12 is because the 3.8.13-bone72 does not appear to allow you to specific which hardware timer to use..  The 4.1.2-bone12 allows a specific timer to be used.

EDIT - 7/21/2015
I have uploaded the debug outputs from a make -d when building the module for both the 3.8.13-bone72 and 4.1.2-bone12 kernels.  There is a difference between the two; it seems to my inexperienced eye that when building against the 4.1.2 kernel it is not switching directories to the kernel source.
If you look at the Debug3.8.txt, you see that after the second "PARTICULAR PURPOSE." line it begins doing things in /home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-3.8.13-bone72/KERNEL and subdirectories.  This does not appear to happen when building against the 4.1.2 kernel though.

LINK: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C46E7B4F8242576!1497&authkey=!AO2GkaEOw41SVC8&ithint=folder%2ctxt

Comment: Your includes might be pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Have you got the header file at `arch/arm/plat-omap/include/plat/dmtimer.h`

Comment: Is `CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP` configuration option is enabled in kernel 4.1.2?

Comment: @LPs: I have verified that dmtimer.h is located in arch/arm/plat-omap/include/plat/ for the 4.1.2 source.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I have verified that CONFIG_ARCH_MAP is enabled in the kernel.

Comment: I have added an EDIT, with some additional information.

Comment: Instead of `make -d` try `make V=1`: it will show complete `gcc` calls. Then check parameters for option "-I": they are actually include directories.

Comment: Have you compiled your kernel before building your module?

Comment: The only difference I found in ur both Makefile is for 4.1.2 kernel toolchain is gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf and for 3.8.13 kernel toolchain is gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.04-20130415_linux.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I did make V=1 and compared the -I and there are locations not being included when compiling against 4.1 that are being included for 3.8, with /arch/arm/plat-omap/include being one of them.  I placed a ccflags-y := /home/tom/ti/Kernel/bb-kernel-4.1.2-bone12/KERNEL/arch/arm/plat-omap/include into my Makefile and it now compiles fine.  I have loaded the module into the BBB and it works.  This raises the question, how is it determined what is automatically included during compilation?  I did not have to specify the dmtimer.h location for 3.8, it was automatically added.

Comment: @vhailor: "how is it determined what is automatically included during compilation?" - Everything is done in Makefile's hierarchy. After inspecting them I found, that without `CONFIG_ARCH_MULTIPLATFORM` defined needed inlude dir should be added automatically (see  KBUILD_CPPFLAGS in `arch/arm/Makefile`). And, in case the option is defined, in-kernel file `arch/arm/plat-omap/Makefile` specifically adds given include directory for build its sources (only for 4.1 version, not for 3.8 one).